# How to import java projects to Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Since I installed Eclipse I have been using it for Android development - mostly. Sometimes I use Oracles Java to do some tests but not more. But about a year ago I developed a rather big program in java that I now would like to import into Eclipse.

Right now I am not able to import the folder (project) into Eclipse. I can only import Android projects, despite I have perspectives for both Java and Android Java.

When I go to **import** I can only choose Android project to import. I have tried to choose **General** in the import meny and then **Existing projects** into workspace - but when I try to do that Eclipse tells me that *there are no projects to import*.

Any ideas how to solve this?

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can always just create a new project and then copy all the source code in and do refresh.

Sometimes you can also copy in the .project and .classpath files into the root of the created project and get all your settings. Usually its easier to just pick your JVM and stuff yourself and then recreate the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project and copy paste the src folder into new one from the older, this trick works perfectly..:)

Answer (score 0):

if you have `.project` file in the importing folder with below entry, then i guess import java project option will be available

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>PROJECT NAME</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            **<name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>**
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        **<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>**
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```